# XSLT 1.0 How to extend with fn (function namespace)

Tags: xslt, function, extend, xslt-1.0

I was wondering how I can possible extend XSLT 1.0 so that I can use functions from fn function namespace at http://www.w3schools.com/Xpath/xpath_functions.asp

I was just told that the system is using MSXML XSLT processor from now on. All my stylesheets were written in 2.0  ... So now I'm stack, nothing is working and don't know how I can use functions for example from fn namespace.

I was wondering whether it will be possible to extend XSLT 1.0 somehow, because I use lots of those functions. Or what do I do now? I'm absolutely lost and frustrated.

Would really appreciate any help!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: An XSLT 1.0 processor like MSXML supports the functions defined in XPath 1.0 http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#corelib and in XSLT 1.0 http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#add-func. If you compare that with what w3schools publishes then you will see that the functions available in XPath 1.0 are a subset of those defined in XPath 2.0. So you can use some of the functions you find on w3schools with MSXML, but of course only those already defined in XPath 1.0, not those newly defined in XPath 2.0.
Basically if you want to work with an XSLT 1.0 processor then using w3schools as a reference is not a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are stuck with MSXML as your processor, I think your only is to go with option 2 in Obalix's answer, but you will probably have to write the extension functions yourself.

Here is an example of how you might do the Upper Case function. This uses javascript within the XSLT to do the function.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
      xmlns:user="http://mycompany.com/mynamespace">

<msxsl:script language="javascript" implements-prefix="user">
   function uppercase(textToConvert) 
   {
      return textToConvert.toUpperCase();
   }
</msxsl:script>

<xsl:template match="text()">
   <xsl:value-of select="user:uppercase(string(.))"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What you could do, is put all the script functions in their own XSLT sheet, and include it in all your own XSLT stylesheets.

How complicated this turns out to be, depends on how many XPath2.0 functions you have used.

Comment: @Tim C thanks a lot. I've noticed you declared msxsl namespace (xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"). I was wondering if you know a good place to read up on MSXML in general, so I can understand it and figure out what I can use... I would really appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how good it is, but you could try this link to it on MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759204(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Well, IMHO, you'r a bit stuck. MSXML, does not implement XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0. So basically you are left with three options:

1. Try to convince you supperiors that they should provide support for another XSLT processor like Saxon.NET.
2. Reimplement all the functions you need using microsoft's msxsl:script function. This should prove difficult and leaves you with a dependency with the Microsoft parser. Furthermore, it only convers the XPath functions - the XSLT 2.0 functionality is not considered here.
3. Reimplement your stylesheets using XSLT 1.0.

Personally, I guess that ony option 1 and 3 are feasible.

Comment: @Obalix Thank you. Unfortinately, they won't change the processor. I was just wondering if I can do anything at all so that I can use functions from http://www.w3schools.com/Xpath/xpath_functions.asp at all? Somehow extend MSXML? Sign. I think I'm in a big pickl.

Comment: Well you can look at http://www.exslt.org/ to see whether there is something you can use, however, unless MS decides to incorporate XSLT 2.0 into ther Processor, you are left alone. But, don't be to donwhearted, I've fallen ito the same trap a while ago.